# Node.js, Express and Mongoose : automatic CRUD API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, restify

Coming from python world, we heavily used tastypie or Django-Rest-framework to create Rest API.

Reading through [Convincing the boss](http://nodeguide.com/convincing_the_boss.html) from Felix Geisendörfer, i noted the following statement:

> Building light-weight REST / JSON api's is something where node.js really shines. Its non-blocking I/O model combined with JavaScript make it a great choice for wrapping other data sources such as databases or web services and exposing them via a JSON interface.

When I try to learn Node.js and find the best way to implement a REST API using existing and reliable modules (like tastypie for Django); I just can't find a node.js module which handle those actions (GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH) based on a model automaticaly.

You will find a lot of tutorials saying how to implement a basic rest api, but I didn't find module ready to be use in a large production app. (i found [Restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/) , [mers](https://github.com/jspears/mers) ...)

What do you guys are using? Existing modules or you prefer developing your own controllers to handle those tasks and creating your own routes manually?

Comment: There's [`methodOverride`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/methodOverride.js) middleware in Connect, which is a middleware layer for Node.js, it brings faux HTTP method support.

Connect is used within [Express](http://expressjs.com/) framework, most popular one for building web apps with ssjs.

Also, check this one https://github.com/AndrewRademacher/auto-crud

Comment: Perhaps you should post the criteria you use to determine if a module is ready (or not) to be used in a large production app.

Comment: Hey @Roman auto-crud seems to be abondened

Answer (score 0):

Check a list of Node.js frameworks, [here](http://nodeframework.com/) for example. A lot of them provide REST out of the box.

Take a look at [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/), for example. With this one you can create a model and get a REST API within seconds.

As for the production-ready thing, it somewhat depends indeed on your own criteria and the requirements you are imposing.